# unable to login to DVR on Internet Explorer - not being prompted for ActiveX add-on

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, dvr

I'm trying to access my DVR system on Internet Explorer (V 11.0.38) but i'm unable to input text in the login field, it's not prompting me to download the ActiveX add-on.

I have one PC where the add-on is installed (same version Internet Explorer) and am able to login just fine.
I've opened the manage add-ons and I see where the ActiveX add-on is saved (it's called RemoteSDK.dll).

I've enabled all ActiveX options in "Internet Option > Security > Custom Level" 
i've also enabled Compatibility mode in "Tools > Compatibility View settings"

how can enable it on other PC's?

Thank You in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you cleared your temp files or tried a different browser?

Comment: @music2myear yes and yes.

Comment: Well, did it work?

Comment: @music2myear still dosen't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is copied the plugin from the PC where it was working and installed the plugin on the other PC, only then did it prompt me to "allow RemoteDVR.dll plugin"

before I installed the plugin I reset all zones to default zones ("Internet Option > Security" )

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed mine by installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 (32bit and 64bit) and did not even have to do a reboot.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14431